# Как организовать множество сцен

Tags: unity3d

Доброе время суток!
Проектирую игрушку на Unity, не могу сообразить как правильно организовать сцены. Скажем есть 50 уровней в платформере, соответсвенно есть 50 сцен(верно это или нет - не знаю), на каждой сцене должно отображаться игровая информация(кол-во жизней, номер уровня и т.д. и т.п.), как организовать вывод этой информации на каждом уровне в одном и том же месте? Сделаю через UI->Text, расположу его на всех сценах, а если понадобиться его сдвинуть на 1 пиксель, что менять во всех сценах? Создавать в динамике, при загрузке сцены, тогда придется в каждой сцене код менять... Как правильно поступить в этом случае?

Comment: Делать UI с привязкой к конкретному уровню - это, конечно, печально. Если вам нужно будет что-то поменять в таком префабе на каждой сцене - вы можете написать скрипт, который будет парсить и изменять значения в файле сцены. Сцена - обычный (ну, почти обычный) текстовый файл с некоторыми значениями, которые можно менять вручную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В такой ситуации более правильным решением будет сделать следующее:

- в проекте лучше иметь одну игровую сцену.
- уровни сохранять в префабы (или, например в ScriptableObject или JSON) и загружать динамически (грубо говоря, по номеру уровня загружать соответствующий префаб с уровнем)
- игровую информацию (весь UI) сверстать на сцене и сохранить также в префаб.

Ваш UI, который содержит информацию об игре лучше хранить в префабе по следующим причинам:

- Есть шанс случайно внести правку в сцену, а точнее в UI. Внести и сохранить правку в префаб случайным образом сложнее, чем по запаре сохранить сцену (например при переключении между сценами
- Вы сможете править верстку параллельно с правкой объектов на сцене. Крайне актуально, если работаете над проектом не один.
- Практика показывает, что при обновлении юнити на более новую версию чаще слетают некоторые настройки именно объектов на сцене, чем настройки префабов.